# Parse Through PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I am trying to parse through and it is throwing back weird results (or I am just overlooking something simple).  Here is a sample print_r of the json_decode from the beginning:

```
Array
(
    [DateGenerated] => 2014-01-12T19:30:21.897
    [Corporation] => Array
        (
            [CorporateBuilderNumber] => MHI
            [CorporateState] => TX
            [CorporateName] => McGuyer Homebuilders, Inc.
            [Builder] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [BuilderNumber] => COV
                            [BrandName] => Coventry Homes
                            [ReportingName] => Coventry Homes
                            [DefaultLeadsEmail] => appsupport@mhinc.com
                            [BuilderWebsite] => http://www.coventryhomes.com
                            [Subdivision] => Array
```

When using this code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");
mysql_select_db("");

$json_data = file_get_contents('mhi.json');
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);

foreach ($json as $value) {
    echo $value['CorporateBuilderNumber'] . "<br />";
    echo $value['CorporateState'] . "<br />";
    echo $value['CorporateName'] . "<br />";
}

?>
```

I get this as the output:

```
2
2
2
MHI
TX
McGuyer Homebuilders, Inc.
```

Where is that 2 coming from?

Comment: `foreach ($json as $key=>$value)`?

Comment: There's no problem with omitting the `$key` in a foreach statement. I feel like the 2's are probably coming from some earlier code. What do you have before your foreach statement?

Comment: I realised what's happening and submitted an answer below.

Comment: @Scopey: Right, I misread.

Comment: You code does nothing to try to handle this as a multi-dimensional array.  I would think you would need to be looking into `$value['Corporation']['CorporateBuilderNumber']`, `$value['Corporation']['CorporateState']`, `$value['Corporation']['Builder'][0]['BuilderNumber']`, and so forth.

Comment: Haha I did overlook having the ['Corporation'] in there... But when I  `echo $value['Corporation']['CorporateBuilderNumber']` I get this returned: `Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array`

Comment: Neither JSON nor PHP implement multi-dimensional arrays - they are hierarchical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time in your loop, `$value` contains `"2014-01-12T19:30:21.897"`.

As you are trying to access `$value['CorporateBuilderNumber']` and that key does not exists, that translates to `$value[0]`, which is the first character of the string, `2`.

Comment: This was the correct answer.  I ended using XML instead and got done what I needed to accomplish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looping through your 'DateGenerated' key first.

All your strings from

```
echo $value['CorporateBuilderNumber'] . "<br />";
echo $value['CorporateState'] . "<br />";
echo $value['CorporateName'] . "<br />";
```

are being converted into int(0), and are referencing the first character of the date you have there, which is a 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your table with this :

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) ){
        foreach( $value as $key2 => $value2){
            if( is_array($values2) ) {
                foreach( $value2 as $key3 => $value3){
                    echo $value3. "<br />";
                }       
            } 
            else{
                echo $value2. "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $value. "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I see what you did there.

Comment: You can continue with more foreach because i saw that there is a fourth array in the sample of your prrint_r